# Why does Tab require the content to be set to null before setting it to something else?

Tags: javafx

The goal is to switch the content of a Tab with the content of a BorderPane and vice versa to create a way to "maximize" the Tab. 
For some reason I have to set the content of the Tab to null before setting it to the real content.

Here is a MCVE:

```
public class FXTests extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        Rectangle content = new Rectangle(100, 100, Paint.valueOf("red"));
        Tab tab = new Tab("tab1", content);
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane(tab);        
        root.setCenter(tabPane);

        Button switchContent = new Button("fill");
        switchContent.setOnAction((e) -> {
            if(switchContent.getText().equals("fill"))
            {
                root.setCenter(tab.getContent());

                switchContent.setText("restore");
            }else
            {                
                root.setCenter(tabPane); 
                System.out.println(tab.getContent());
                tab.setContent(null); //why is this required?
                tab.setContent(content);

                switchContent.setText("fill");
            }
        });
        root.setTop(switchContent);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Is this a bug in JavaFX or is it expected behavior?

Java version: 1.8.0_141

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) documentation:

> If a program adds a child node to a Parent (including Group, Region, etc) and that node is already a child of a different Parent or the root of a Scene, the node is automatically (and silently) removed from its former parent.

A TabPane control is internally backed by a skin which, in this case, is a container containing a hierarchy of nodes.  When you press your "fill" button and set the center of your borderPane to directly reference the content node, then the system will silently remove the content from the tab's skin.  When you press your "restore" button, the tab pane will be displayed without the content there (as it was silently removed).

It looks like the silent removal of the content from the skin does not provide a notification to the tab control object so the tab control object still shows a reference to the content, even when the content is no longer in the skin.  My guess is that setting the value of the content of the tab to null, then back to the content, causes the tab to update the skin hierarchy to reference the content again.

---

IMO, a better way to handle this is to be careful when you are coding and try to ensure that you never trigger a silent removal of a node.  You can do this by explicitly removing the node in code (by explicitly removing the content from the tab pane before you set it to the border pane center).  Then you don't end up with any weird mismatch of internal state between the tab pane control and its skin.

Something like this (it's not much different, but to me is easier to understand and explain):

```
Node tabContent = tab.getContent();

Button switchContent = new Button("fill");
switchContent.setOnAction((e) -> {
    if (switchContent.getText().equals("fill")) {
        tab.setContent(null);
        root.setCenter(tabContent);

        switchContent.setText("restore");
    } else {
        root.setCenter(tabPane);
        tab.setContent(tabContent);

        switchContent.setText("fill");
    }
});
```

Note, the above code snippet assumes the tab content was preinitialized and set within the tab and that you don't change the tab content elsewhere in the application (if you do, then you need to be a bit more careful with the coding and have some more logic in there to handle such external changes).

Comment: Now it all makes sense. Thank you for your detailed answer!